# Python equivalent of getOrElse

Tags: python

In languages with optional types, you have a fn called `orElse` or `getOrElse` which lets you do this:

```
None.getOrElse(1) == 1
Some(2).getOrElse(1) == 2
```

I.e. you can specify a default value. In Python, I find I am writing:

```
if output_directory:
    path = output_directory
else:
    path = '.'
```

and it would be cleaner with a `getOrElse` call. Searching for orElse and getOrElse turns up logical operators. Is there a suitable Python fn?

Edit: getOrElse is not the same as a ternary operator call because that requires you to reference `output_directory` *twice*. Which is a particular issue if it's replaced with a complex expression. (Quite normal in a functional style.)

Comment: The closest you can get is using a ternary: `path = output_directory if output_directory else '.'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 8):

Note that the above solution does not work precisely like the canonical `getOrElse` semantics of an FP language such as Scala or Haskell in corner cases where the `bool(x) == False`. For example

```py
Some(0).getOrElse(1) == 0
Some('').getOrElse('A') == ''
```

but for either of the two definitions below

```py
def getOrElse1(x, y):
  return x or y

def getOrElse2(x, y):
  return x if x else y
```

we have

```
getOrElse(x=0, 1) == 1
getOrElse(x='', 'A') == 'A'
```

An equivalent semantics is given by the definition:

```py
def getOrElse(x, y):
  return x if x is not None else y
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use `or` for equivalent logic:

```
path = output_directory or '.'
```

Comment: This is not correct. The or operator does not check for `None` but for `False` after conversion to `bool`. There is WIP: https://peps.python.org/pep-0505/

Comment: @Arne Thank you for pointing that out! Please write an answer and I will delete this answer

Comment: Could you delete it anyway? Almost used it. I don't think he'll post an answer detailing what *doesn't* work

Comment: Can’t delete an accepted answer- flagged for deletion instead

Answer (score 0):

As commented above the `or` will not work as intended if the value of `output_directory` is falsy. For example `output_directory = ""` would cause the default to be chosen. Being fair, the original code block assumes that as well.

Using a Ternary at least puts things on one line.

```
path = output_directory if output_directory is not None else '.'
```